# GCCのコンパイル時のウォーニングメッセージ

Tags: gcc

現在、GCCを使ってアプリケーションを修正しています。
前任者の作成したCMakeFilesを使っていますので、よくわからない内容があります。
エラーではありませんが、次のウォーニングメッセージが出ています。
どういうウォーニングメッセージで、どうすればいいのかわかる方いましたら、教えてください。

```
/home/user/util.h:114:53: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules [-Wstrict-aliasing]
     pc.r = reinterpret_cast<const float &&>(r);
```

環境は次のとおりです。

Ubuntu 16.04
GCC

よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 0):

検索すると、キャストが不適切と出ますが、違いますか?

> /home/user/util.h:114:53

util.h の 114行目あたりでしょうか?

> `pc.r = reinterpret_cast<const float &&>(r);`

このキャストが問題のようです。コンパイルオプション "-Wstrict-aliasing" を使っていますか?
これによる指摘では無いかと。